# Provide two .csv files with one header/HTTP transaction

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I currently have code that will generate a CSV from a database call, but I've been asked to create two separate CSV files with two different database calls from one click event. Here is an example of my current code:

```
'Global variable
Dim Include As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)


'Click event sub
Dim tempID As String = ""

'This gets the value of a checkbox (7th of 7 columns)
' and only adds checked rows to the query.
For Each row In GridView.Rows
    If row.Cells(6).Controls(1).Checked Then
        tempID = Regex.Replace(row.Cells(0).Controls(0).Text.Trim, "<(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|=""[^""]*""|=[^'""][^\s>]*)*>", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace Or RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.Singleline)
        Include.Add(tempID)
    End If
Next

Dim Chosen As String = String.Join(",", Include)

SQLQuery = "SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT ON; "
SQLQuery += "SELECT * FROM ( " &
SQLQuery += "SELECT EXP.Account, " &
    "EXP.Amount, " &
    "EXP.DebitCredit, " &
    "EXP.Description, " &
    "EXP.BudgetCenter "

SQLQuery += "FROM [DB].[TBL] EXP " &
    "INNER JOIN [DB2].[TBL2] REIM " &
    "ON EXP.ID = REIM.ID " &
    "WHERE EXP.ID IN ( " + Chosen + " ) " &
    "AND REIM.StatusCode = 'APPROVED' "

SQLQuery += ") AS ResultTable "
ResultsDataSet = RunQuery(SQLQuery) 'THIS IS WHERE I CALL THE DATABASE
ResultsTable = ResultsDataSet.Tables(0)

For Each row As DataRow In ResultsTable.Rows
    Dim item As String
    For Each item In row.ItemArray
        sb.Append(item.ToString + ","c)
    Next
Next

Response.Clear()
Response.Buffer = True
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=JournalReport_" + Date.Today.Month.ToString + "_" + Date.Today.Day.ToString + "_" + Date.Today.Year.ToString + ".csv")
Response.Charset = ""
Response.ContentType = "application/text"
Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString())
Response.Flush()
```

I have another `click event` that does the same thing, but with a different query and a different file name in the `Response.AddHeader()` call.

What I'm trying to do is to, in a way, merge those two click events to create both files in one action. Is there a way I can do this with the code I have? Is there a different way I should be creating these files?

I've written this code with the help of research on GridViews and DataSets over the last few days. So, if it isn't pretty, it's only because it's been a bit rushed and has little knowledge behind it.

Comment: Where does `Chosen` come from? That could be a very serious SQL Injection security issue.

Comment: Also... it's **IMPOSSIBLE** to respond to _one_ HTTP request with _two_ separate documents, unless you're willing to also put them into a single zip file. I challenge you to find and show me even one time you've clicked a single link on a web page and caused two separate downloads to happen.

Comment: This is an internal facing web application. So, the SQL injection isn't a concern. I've added the line with Chosen, I forgot to put that in.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out SOME way to do what you call impossible. A redirect? A zip file might be okay.

Comment: Balonga. Internal sites still need SQL injection protection.

Comment: I agree, but that concern will go on the back burner for now.

Comment: Maybe javascript to open separate tabs for the extra downloads.

Comment: Would the zip file be an option, or was that just a wild thought?

Comment: You can do that, but its rarely what users expect or wanted.

Comment: Okay. Well, how would I do the zip, and what other options do you think there are. JS isn't really welcomed in this project, unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178961/discussion-between-brettwbyron-and-joel-coehoorn).